# Promise trouble! How can I write this in such a way that it waits for the end?

Tags: javascript, promise

Trying to write this in a way that it will wait for the db operations to complete. Possible?

```
function addFriendsToSession(session, sessionId) {
    const friends = [];

    const incoming = session.users.forEach(async user => {
        console.log('user', user);
        await db
            .collection('users/' + user + '/settings')
            .doc(user)
            .get()
            .then(doc => {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    const returnObj = doc.data();
                    return returnObj.friends ? returnObj.friends : [];
                } else {
                    return [];
                }
            });
    });
    friends.push(incoming);
    return friends;
}
```

Comment: Removed firestore tag as this is not specific to Firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

`Promise.all` accepts an array of promises, and resolves once each promise has resolved.  You can map your operation using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).  E.g.,

```
const promises = session.users.map(user => {
    console.log('user', user);
    return db
        .collection('users/' + user + '/settings')
        .doc(user)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                const returnObj = doc.data();
                return returnObj.friends ? returnObj.friends : [];
            } else {
                return [];
            }
        });
});

const friends = await Promise.all(promises)

return friends;
```

Comment: You say `Promise.all(()` but code shows `Promise.wait()`. Typo?

Comment: Yes, thanks.. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues here.

1. In `db.then()`, `return` is used, but this value is never returned from the function that encloses it (which is `async user => {...}`)
2. `const incoming` is assigned the result of `session.users.forEach`, but `Array.forEach()` never has a return value (you may be thinking of `Array.map()`?)
3. Even if you solved the first two problems, `incoming` would still be an array of Promises

Additional suggestions:

- Don't mix async/await with .then

Putting it all together:

```
const incoming = session.users.map(async user => {
    console.log('user', user);
    const doc = await db
        .collection('users/' + user + '/settings')
        .doc(user)
        .get();
        //we assigned `doc` using await instead of using .then
    if (doc.exists) {
        const returnObj = doc.data();
        return returnObj.friends ? returnObj.friends : [];
    } else {
        return [];
    }
});
//incoming is not an array of Promises
const incomingFriends = await Promise.all(incoming); //takes an array of Promises and returns an array of the resolved values
//incomingFriends is now an array of friends

//next line would make the last element an array
//friends.push(incoming); 
//you probably want to push every element of the array
friends.push(...incomingFriends);
```

Comment: I have always struggled with promises and async/await helped me but when they mix I never know what is going on! Thanks!!!

Comment: In rare cases, you may want to `await promise.then()`, but it's unlikely, and ya, otherwise it makes it easier to get lost!